# How to get hierarchical organisational data using LINQ?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have some organisation tables which are linked to an OrgUser table.

OrgUser >- Org -< OrgLink
               -<

There are 2 1toMany links to OrgLink with one being ParentOrg and the other be ChildOrg.

So a typical example would be Joe Bloggs who works in the "Small Business Unit" which is part of the "Business Department".

There is a record in OrgLink which points "Business Department" to its child org of "Small Business Unit" which has an OrgUser called "Joe BLoggs".

If I am logged in as "Joe Bloggs" then I would like to get a list of all the immediate and parental orgs that he is linked to, so in this case I would hope to get "Small Business Unit" and "Business Department". I can get the immediate org, but the parent bit is confusing me. Also if there is no parent then just the immediate org should be returned. Basically all orgs linked to the immediate org should be returned.

My LINQ so far:

```
 from SOU in StdOrgUser
                    join SO in StdOrg on SOU.StdOrgId equals SO.Id 
                    where SOU.UserId.Equals(new Guid("42995B01-97C8-4148-8EA3-5CCC55535194"))   
                    select new { OrgName=SO.Name, Col2= SOU.UserId, c3=SO.StdOrgType.Name}
```

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT/UPDATE:

Having researched this I have found that I do not need the JOIN or INCLUDE since my EF model has the required associations and therefore appear as navigational properties. I ended up using a UNION with 2 LINQ queries, thus the pseudocode is:

```
var results1 = Get child organisation that UserId works for.
var results2 = Get parent organisation for child organisation if it exists.
var results3 = results1.Union(results2)

foreach org in results3
{
 console.writeline(org.Id);
 console.writeline(org.Name);
}
```

I am sure there is a more eloquent approach, and do feel free to suggest, but this approach does work. Perhaps when my knowledge of LINQ get better I will find it myself!

Comment: Firstly? Are you using L2S or EF? Secondly did you setup the associations up correctly. If so you shouldn't be using JOIN.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using EF5. Yes I believe I have setup the relationships correctly. I spent a little while doing this, especially in the ORM designer. I do admit that I am a newbie to LINQ hence the reason for the JOINS.... Also my background is SQL.

Comment: You would normally want `from u in context.Users.Include(x => x.BusinessUnit) where u.UserId == new Guid("xxx") select u;`

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the delay. Have been working away at this. See EDIT in question body.

Comment: Closing this now and awarind points. Greatly appreciate help, although I went with my own solution in the end. Many thanks.